# Parse socket.io data on android. (Gottox Socket.IO)

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I'm using a node.js server and I used the Socket.IO chat example for reference with Android.
Here's what's in my app.js file

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
```

Here is my html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Android code.

```
try {
        SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.0.5:8080");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Server","Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                Log.e("Server","Server said: " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                Log.e("Server",socketIOException.toString());
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                Log.e("Server","Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                Log.e("Server","Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                Log.e("Server","Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }

        });
        socket.send("Hello Server!");
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){

    }
```

Most of the code works fine. The problem is that from the website side,if I send a message,it doesn't log on android. 
I'm receiving this in the log from the default log function in the library.

```
12-22 14:30:36.131: I/io.socket(3262): < 5:::{"name":"chat message","args":["sdfg"]}
```

Comment: hy there. Were you able to solve your problem. Currently i am also facing the same problem as you are. Could you help me out if you hav the solution. That would be a great help and i would really appreciate it. plus 1 for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270345/node-js-and-websocket-in-android-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below, it maybe of some help to you for accessing the data sent from your website to your Android application,
http://nkzawa.tumblr.com/post/46850605422/connecting-to-a-socket-io-server-from-android
Hope it helps